# CakePHP remove the index action from the URL

Tags: php, cakephp, routes, url-routing

How do I remove the index action from the URL?

Here is my code in `routes.php`

```
Router::connect('/jobs/:slug',array('controller'=>'jobs','action'=>'index'));
```

So basically, i have this url:

```
http://example.com/jobs/index/pharmacist
```

but I want to change that one into

```
http://example.com/jobs/pharmacist
```

Would this configuration be purely in `routes.php` or I should need to edit my `.htaccess`, I honestly absolutely don't have any idea.

Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: [Read This (Cakephp URL rewriting)](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html) and ensure step **2** is properly set.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#passing-parameters-to-action)

By using the 3rd argument of `Router::connect()` you can define which route elements should also be made available as passed arguments:

```
Router::connect('/jobs/:slug',array('controller'=>'jobs','action'=>'index'), array('pass' => array('slug')));
```

and in your view you can generate link using

```
echo $this->Html->link('link', array(
    'controller' => 'jobs',
    'action' => 'index',
    'slug' => 'your_slug'
));
```